# Find the sup-norm

Tags: normed-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

Find the sup-norm, $\|f\|_{\sup}$, if

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
0, &x \in\mathbb{Q}\\
-x^2, &x\not\in\mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}$$

As I look at the graph of $-x^2$, I know it's a decreasing function. I know the sup-norm is infinity. I'm not sure why that is though.

Comment: This is very difficult to read. Please edit and type using Latex commands.

Answer (score 1):

Since $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ -x^2 & x \notin \mathbb{Q} \end{cases},$$

we have
$$|f(x)| = \begin{cases} 0 & x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ x^2 & x \notin \mathbb{Q} \end{cases}.$$

Notice that $x^2$ can get arbitrary large.

hence $$\left\| f\right\|_\infty= \sup\{|f(x)|: x\in \mathbb{R} \}= \infty$$

Comment: Thank you so much! Makes much more sense.

Comment: Consider selecting Siong's answer as accepted.